# Properties of a circle detected using HoughCircles

Tags: opencv, contour, hough-transform

My aim is to find out the properties of circles that I have detected using cv::HoughCircles(). Basically I want to find out the pixel intensities inside the circle which I intend to do to check how bright/dark the detected circle is. Could anyone guide me in the right direction in achieving this?

Comment: You want to use masking. You can create a mask from the detected circles easily by drawing the circle filled with a white color on an otherwise empty (black) `Mat`. You can then use that mask in computations to only do the computations in the white area of the mask. For e.g., [`meanStdDev()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga846c858f4004d59493d7c6a4354b301d) takes a `mask` parameter, so you can calculate the mean and standard deviations of the intensities of the picture only in the areas where the mask is white. Many other OpenCV methods also have a `mask` param.

Comment: Another possibility which is sometimes useful is to use `bitwise_and()` to make a masked image---in this case, the output image from `bitwise_and()` will be black anywhere that the mask is black, and will otherwise retain the same color values as your image where the mask is white. For example, if you wanted to add all the intensities of your image inside the mask, then create a masked image and pass that to `sum()`; everything outside the mask will be set to 0 so they won't affect the total.